Is it possible to dynamically define the values in GitHub Actions workflow input block?
According to GitHub Actions workflow inputs should be defined statically within the workflow file.
Is it possible to have the input values fetched dynamically when the workflow starts?
E.g., I've a workflow to deploy an docker image to AWS ECS.
The input to workflow is the image tag. Instead of having a string field, I would like to fetch first the image tags from AWS ECR (aws ecr list-images) and then display those tags as inputs to the workflow.

While I can see the appeal, I don't believe you can dynamically set workflow inputs.  You can fetch things dynamically and then expose as an output to subsequent jobs or steps, but I don't know of a way to prompt the user to choose from them after the jobs are started.

Just reading about your given scenario, I would publish the images with a commit sha (or first 7), and then they can choose the branch  / commit of that job to run the workflow.   Might be worth thinking about.  That's what we do to deploy image artifacts to prod

Currently it's impossible in GitHub Actions, there is a popular feature request about it:
https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/12029
As a workaround what you can do is - create a side workflow which fetch the tags from ECR and update the workflow YAML (the input choice) with the values.
